# Error using "call" to.py script from a .bat file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-import

I have a .bat file such as:

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
call .\setup_1 %1 %2
call .\setup_2.bat %1 %2
call .\setup_3.py %1 %2
pause
```

Which calls several .bat scripts succesfully, but when it calls the .py file it gives error after trying to execute it:

> ImportError: No module named subprocess

The py file looks like this:

```
import os
print("before import subprocess")
import subprocess
print("after import subprocess")
import sys
```

And the error show is:

```
before import subprocess 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\local_path\setup_3.py", line 3, in ? 
    import subprocess 
ImportError: No module named subprocess
```

I'm using python 3.7.2, and I have python included in the `PATH`. Other colleagues can run this bat file without any problems.

If I change the call by the following instruction it works well, but this is not a solution, as we share the same repository and it should work with the call instruction.

```
python.exe .\setup_3.py %1 %2
```

Any idea of which configuration should be changed to make this work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try adding a `print(sys.version)` to be sure of what python version is really used ?

Comment: @AlvaroMuro: You would need to do an `import sys` first.

Comment: Yes @Blusky, and it confirms it's using 3.7.2: 

`3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: Can you run python scripts directly from the command line? Usually one needs to prefix it like this `python my_script.py` or maybe `py my_script.py`.

Comment: @martineau: Yes if I run from cmd it executes setup_3.py correctly

Comment: Well, even so, try changing the `call` in your `.bat` file explicitly invoke `python` and see if that helps. The symptoms look like the Python interpreter isn't finding the standard library for some reason.

Comment: @martineau: yes, invoking `python` instead using `call` in the bat works, I'm trying to find a way to make `call` work, as it does in other computers around with the same script

Comment: Why do you care how the script is being run? Shouldn't make too much difference (other than working).

Comment: @martineau: because it's an automated prebuild action of a project in a repository shared by many people for production code, and having different implementations for each user is not convenient

Comment: Explicitly using `python` is portable, so no worries there.

Comment: The [`call` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) is intended to call other batch files or sub-routines (labels) within a batch file, but not for starting an external executable (like `python.exe`), so you are simply trying to use the wrong thing for your goal; you will have to use `python.exe`, or, if the `.py` file extension is associated with it (as usual), try [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)`[/WAIT]`, alternatively...